# Make tooltip text ending on user tab sorting order consistent. Only the "participation" tab contains dot at the end

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, tooltips, grammar, participation

Tooltip for "participation" tab contains the `.` at the end, but there's no dot for all other tabs:

> [image]

I suggest to remove it here as well. Adding the dot to the all other instead I can't consider as an alternative option just because it will only burden the data on the screen.

Answer (score -2):

Not writing a dot at the end of a sentence is grammatically incorrect, BUT in a real word, when we are just chatting with each other, we usually do not write a dot at the end of the last sentence. As I understand that SO is not a place for official conversations, so it's better for me not to write a dot at the end of the last sentences